# как отправлять транзакции trx с помощью python

Tags: python, requests, tron

вот код который я использовал

```
from tronpy import Tron
from tronpy.keys import PrivateKey

client = Tron(network='mainnet')
priv_key = PrivateKey(bytes.fromhex("privete_key"))

txn = (
   client.trx.transfer("from_adress", "to_adress",2)
   .memo("test memo")
   .build()
   .sign(priv_key)
)
print(txn.txid)
print(txn.broadcast().wait())
```

Возвращалась ошибка

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/getsignweight
```